# I have not received my bitcoin after 2 days and 115 confirmations

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

I have sent my first Transaction and waiting for it to arrive at another address but when i click on the Transaction ID 1 of the addresses is Spent and the other is Unspent? It only required 3 Confirmations but is now 115? Where is my bitcoin and how do i receive it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post the txid or receiving address? More info is needed to provide meaningful help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, here is the Transaction ID if this helps:

https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/tx/0ec3e57ee26a68f73030f331fa18184bc3290833fb5b40509caedbd434c99301

Answer (score 0):

> **1 of the addresses is Spent and the other is Unspent?**

The simplest transaction has one input and two outputs. One output is the amount to be transferred to the destination-address. The other output is the left-over change being returned to the sender (to the wallet containing the sending-address).

One way of interpreting what you wrote is that the recipient has already spent what you sent them.

Another way of interpreting what you wrote is that you have subsequently spent the change in a second transaction.

> **It only required 3 Confirmations but is now 115?**

The transaction is confirmed. It is not pending. If you wait longer nothing will change.

> **Where is my bitcoin**

Someone has already spent it (i.e. spent the amount sent or the change returned).

> **and how do i receive it?**

It has already been received.

---

You don't say explicitly that you "own" the sending address and both of the receiving addresses (perhaps in more than one wallet) but if so, your wallet has been compromised and you should immediately move everything into a completely new [cold wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/81246/13866)

---

lets look at the transaction

```
Transaction: 0ec3e57ee26a68f73030f331fa18184bc3290833fb5b40509caedbd434c99301

Source of funds: Address: 18gLw9DF8aBW2PzY3rVi35bFiuSTNgiv7s 
                 Amount:  0.02849847 BTC

Outputs:         0.02054938 BTC to 16FsHnvTqnYrvdPXTH4c7tXD8ZE4r8rXJg - (Unspent)   
                 0.00781349 BTC to 1NtLEd3y5wEmR3bsQ1LEeN6g8H3DbxSmiU - (Spent)
```

Only you know which is the amount transferred and which is the left-over change. So only you know whether the amount or the change has been spent.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I sent this bitcoin from my Exodus wallet to a website and then this was getting returned to the same Exodus wallet, but i have not received anything, even the Unspent? Are you saying that i maybe have been scammed  and this will never be received?

Comment: @BigKris64: I can't tell. What website did you use and who said they would return money to you? Did you check how long the website's domain name has been registered. Did you check what business owns the website and in which country it is registered - and for how long? Is this part of a get-rich-quick scheme? Its only 82 dollars (or maybe 31 dollars) no big loss.

Comment: Yeah your right i should have did more research into the website. It was $114 which $83 is Unspent and $31 is Spent, does this mean the $83 will be returned to the sender which is me? And ifso how long Thanks

Comment: @BigKris64: You already asked that and I answered above. There's nothing in what you wrote that suggests waiting will alter the situation to your benefit. If $83 is change it is already in your wallet somewhere. Change is handled as part of the spending transaction it does not require a second transaction to get change back.