# Recovery of lost bitcoin

Tags: blockchain

i have my wallet id and bitcoin address in a safe but deleted from all electronic gadgets. So how do i recover my bitcoin by using these said method please advise.

Comment: What do you mean with wallet id? Addresses cannot help u recover funds. You need the root seed or mnemonic backup phrase of ur previous wallet.

Answer (score 4):

> **I have my wallet id and bitcoin address [...] how do i recover my bitcoin by using these?**

You cannot recover control over Bitcoin using only a [Bitcoin address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address).

You cannot recover control over Bitcoin using only a "[Wallet-ID](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000813966-What-is-a-wallet-ID-)" you typically [need a password](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/211205343-I-forgot-my-password-What-can-you-do-to-help-) also. But in the case of custodial wallets, the custodian *may* provide a [means of recovery](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000476563) based on other information (e.g. an email address used for original registration). Note that custodial wallets are widely regarded as the least secure way to store Bitcoin long term. See [What kinds of wallets are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866). Also note that private companies like Blockchain.com don't own either the Bitcoin system or the Bitcoin blockchain - they are just one of many businesses that offer services based on cryptocurrencies.

---

You generally need either

- The [Private Key](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key) in some well-known format (e.g. WIF) or
- A [seed recovery phrase](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase) (often 12 words from a special list)

If you don't have these, it usually means your Bitcoin are forever unusable.