# How to create an online Bitcoin account?

Tags: introducing-bitcoin

I am new to the `Bitcoin` world. I want to know what are the procedures / steps to do in order to create a `Bitcoin` online account ? What are the popular `Bitcoin` online sites for creating an account ? For analogy for example with VISA cards there is `www.paypal.com` ; so what is for the `Bitcoin` ?

Comment: Note that Bitcoin is a currency, not (primarily) a payment mechanism. As such it compares with things like the USD or EUR; not with Visa.

Comment: You might like to review [What kinds of wallets are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866)