# Can I recover my money in a Coinbase Wallet?

Tags: wallet-recovery, coinbase.com

I just want to ask if there is possibility to recover my money in a Coinbase wallet. I forgot my recovery phrase but I remember my wallet address and TXID.

Answer (score 2):

According to [coinbase](https://wallet.coinbase.com/faq/)

> Wallet is a user-custodied digital currency wallet and DApp browser. This means that with Wallet, the private keys (that represent ownership of the cryptocurrency) are stored directly on your device and not with a centralized exchange like Coinbase Consumer. You do not need a Coinbase Consumer account to use Wallet and you can download Wallet from anywhere in the world.

You cannot recover control over money in a user-custodied wallet using only a Bitcoin-address and a Transaction ID.

If you have somehow lost your wallet (e.g. phone dropped into ocean) - without the recovery phrase or some other equivalent sort of backup, your money is gone forever.

---

If by "Coinbase Wallet" you actually mean "Coinbase Consumer" - that is a [custodial-wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866) (or equivalent service) and your only possible way to recover control over your money is to communicate with the help-desk of Coinbase.