# I have two accounts and can't fin my original one

Tags: money-transfer

I'm new to Bitcoin. I opened an account to transfer cash from an online betting site. After doing so, my computer crashed I lost all connections and info except my Bitcoin address. I opened a new Bitcoin account and now when I log in, it takes me to the new account. I can't get logged in to my original account and find my money.
Thanks, Brian

Comment: A bitcoin address is not sufficient information to recover a wallet. We'll need more info to help you. Which wallet did you use? Did you make any backups of it in any way?

Comment: Do you use the wallet bitcoin core?

Comment: From what you wrote, it looks like instead of downloading wallet software you opened an account at some business who controls money on your behalf instead of you directly controlling your own money. If so, you need to contact that specific business. See [Types of wallet - Custodial](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866)