# Bcoiner wallet - balance is showing as zero?

Tags: wallet

please help! I sent to my wallet 450 dolars of bitcoin, and transactions are confirmed strongly 62 times, but my wallet says that I have 0 bitcoins to spent and I cant sell it!!! What to do? Whats happening? thank you so much for answers!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What wallet is this? Can you post a transaction ID or receiving address?

Comment: I add one more screenshot in post above. its a bcoiner app. First time here, thanks for understanding.

Comment: I meant bcoiner wallet. Its a scam isnt it? 450 dollars!!!!!

Comment: The transactions paying to you were confirmed, but there have been a few subsequent transactions moving those coins to new addresses: txID 4d88a869b354b64a14d384939d1d801966733b892c07c189e9ceace3a57c49bd and then txID cb1fc617b635f851d79123f5e1fe16c98948c421445007ca11a2050ed4213355. The coins now reside at address 14qCMrBxt21idaa9FzZ5VBUKpy3rztXEvF. --- I am unfamiliar with bcoiner wallet, but a quick search reveals a help page on their site. If you did not make those transactions I would recommend contacting them to see if they can help.

Comment: In general, I would recommend using wallets that are well-known and well-reviewed (and most definitely, open source!). Bitcoin.org has a list of recommended wallets that is a good place to start from.

Comment: I already did. they answered me with some bullshit. I mail them again, no answers. So I guess I lost that , ha?

Comment: Happy to help. I do hope that you have not been scammed, and considering a lot of the world is celebrating holidays right now, maybe the support staff is just on vacation (wishful thinking, maybe). But otherwise, it is definitely best to stick to known wallets, and make sure you download them from trusted sources (or build from source code yourself).

Comment: thank you for the optimism. I hope so too. It's still writing in my wallet that I received 450 dollars and I didn't send it anywhere, so let's hope! Thank you! I will be much smarter next time!

Comment: @user101526 https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/14qCMrBxt21idaa9FzZ5VBUKpy3rztXEvF - No the coins are spent shown here few hours ago did you cash it out

Comment: @user101526 I'd recommend www.blockchain.com they have a wallet that is fantastic btw I also hav ledger, a hardware wallet. They never had any problems I used it so far

Comment: @user101526 - I think it maybe just a bug in bcoiner wallet since they've shown the value?

Comment: @Duckduckgaga I would recommend avoiding the blockchain.com wallet. See https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet for some well-respected choices.

Answer (score 2):

> **Whats happening here**

As others have commented, the money was received by the address in your wallet but was subsequently spent.

Since your wallet doesn't show the expected balance but also does not show the spends it seems there is some flaw in the app or in the service behind it. Whether this is a malicious flaw is impossible to say.

Since you didn't spend that money, someone else must have. That suggests the wallet has been compromised or the underlying account in the bcoiner service has been compromised.

Since bcoiner support have been unable to resolve this to your satisfaction, it might be prudent to avoid putting any more money into this wallet.

---

The bcoiner wallet is not an app I personally would use for the following reasons:

- **Unresolved woe** - There are several stories similar to your own on this website. All wallets have some such stories associated with them but most also have some history of such problems being resolved or being found to have a more reasonable explanation than possible theft by app developers.
- **Suspicious review profile** = Profile of reviews on Google Play seems suspicious to me. There are many 5-star reviews obscuring 1-star reviews (mostly similar experience to yours) and *not much in between*. Either this is a great wallet with some flaws or somebody is submitting fake 5-star reviews in a way that Google Play doesn't detect. The developers responses to the 1-star reviews are rather uniform and unhelpful. The evidence here is very weak, but I'm inclined to be cautious when choosing software that has control over money.
- **Custodial?** - I have seen [allegations](https://walletscrutiny.com/android/com.bcoiner.webviewapp/) that this is a [custodial wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866). I would not want to use a custodial wallet.
- **Not open-source** - It is proprietary closed-source not open-source, I prefer open-source wallets.

In the end I suggest you make a decision based on the quality of support you receive from bcoiner developers and from the community of bcoiner users.

---

It may be worth [searching this site for other questions about bcoiner](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=bcoiner+is%3Aq) and using that information to help you to decide what action to take and whether to [select a more popular and better supported wallet app](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet).

---

### Appendix - Google Play reviews:

1. Bcoiner - too good to be true? surprisingly polarised?
   [image: bcoiner ratings barchart]
2. Mycelium
   [image: Mycelium ratings barchart]
3. Blockchain (their non-custodial app, not their custodial wallet service)
   [image: blockchain ratings barchart]
4. Bitcoin Wallet (Schildbach)
   [image: schildbach ratings barchart]
5. Electrum - A formerly well-regarded wallet afflicted by a security flaw and a badly received recent update?
   [image: Electrum ratings barchart]

I found it revealing to actually read the reviews sorted by newest first and get a feel for the range of feelings expressed and the variety of subject matter and writing styles. Doing this for several wallets gives you an impression of what is normal and what is not.