# Transaction pending unconfirmed for a very long time --- Done with Bcoiner App

Tags: client, unconfirmed-transactions, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-wallet-app, money

I sent bitcoin to someone 8 days ago and since then no confirmations have been done but myself someone sent bitcoin sameday and got many confirmations sametime. So i tried to resend the bitcoin about 3 times but still no confirmation and when i go to check on blockchain using the details information for the transaction ID it says its invalid, there's no such transaction yet on my side it shows unconfirmed and pending 0 and now its been 7 days. I was hoping this could be done soon as i want my friend to receive her bitcoin and send cash to me urgently coz i need to use it urgently. Please kindly help, i have never had a bad experience when it comes to bitcoin and this is my first time using bcoiner app so please help me, need this sorted coz my friend thinks i have not sent the bitcoin to her and now its a problem coz she is now asking why i used bcoiner. I tried sending emails to the email address provided on their site but no response has come. I send emails everyday but no one responds. I really need this to be sorted as i didnt expect this to happen. I never did research about the app, i just signed up recently. Please can anyone help me in this. Even my balance shows that the money left is 4usd meaning it has gone but not to my friend coz it hasnt been confirmed. I'd like this to be sent back to me so i can maybe send it to another wallet or if there is a way of withdrawing the money.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bcoiner wallet - balance is showing as zero?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92506/bcoiner-wallet-balance-is-showing-as-zero)

Answer (score 0):

Use well known wallets like Muun or Bitcoin Core or Electrum. Any low quality or low popularity wallets is a no no