# What happened to my bitcoin? 0 balance

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions, funds

I logged in to my blockchain.com  wallet to find my bitcoin are all gone. The log of my bitcoin transactions is also wiped clean. The only thing that is still there is a log of my past ether transactions. When I use the blockchain explorer to search for the two public keys that were used to transfer the bitcoin to my account it says both public keys are "unspent". I've tried opening a support ticket with blockchain.com, but no response. What has happened to my bitcoin? Is this some sort of technical glitch?

I still have the notification on my phone from when I received the BTC last month
[image]

Comment: I have seen reports of this from many blockchain(dot)com wallet users in recent days, it appears to be a glitch in their wallet interface. You should contact their customer service for more info, and then I would recommend choosing new wallet software that doesn't have a long history of issues like this.

Comment: Hi @Eric, I think is a interface glitch.
If you have the 12 or 24 mnemonic words you can restore your wallet on another app to check your balance.
Remember take the mnemonic words absolutely private!

Comment: any recommendations on which wallet to switch to?

Comment: BRD, Electrum, CoPay, Mycelium are all good wallets, any would do. (I've used all of them except Mycelium; my favourite is BRD though you can just compare them and use the one you like the most.)

Comment: @aqquadro I have no idea how to use the mnemonic words to restore a wallet. how can I be sure where ever I enter the words is not compromising the wallet entirely?

Comment: The amount of trust of the wallet software is the main risk, but is only a trust matter: the software can steal your bitcoins. There isn't any technical problems, at the same time you can have multiple wallet software that manage your keys. Obviously more software have your keys and more your keys are exposed :)

If you are able to BYOB surely is the best way using official software available on https://bitcoin.org/.
Btw simplified but also secure solutions are https://www.ledger.com/ and https://tezos.com/.
The best way to start choosing is https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet.

Comment: @Eric never enter the mnemonic words (recovery phrase) online. It is safe to enter them on a computer (PC, phone, hardware-wallet etc)  that is disconnected from the internet (no Ethernet, no WiFi, no 3/4/5g data). To get the balance the computer would have to be reconnected to the internet but this should be relatively safe if the computer is checked free from viruses/malware and you are using a well-known wallet program downloaded from the proper website (beware fakes)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick So are you saying all of these wallet websites like blockchain.com are not safe? The only safe thing to do is to have an offline wallet and only enter my password while disconnected from the internet? PS I still have not heard back from blockchain.com regarding all my btc being gone.

Comment: @Eric: your wallet's password is not the mnemonic-words. The mnemonic-words are a recovery-phrase also known as a seed-phrase. You use the wallet password every time you run the wallet program. You never use the mnemonic words except when you need to re-create a wallet - usually after a disaster of some sort. And yes, wallets based on websites (custodial wallets) are the least safe form of wallet, Google MtGox and Quadriga. The safest wallet for long-term storage (months or years) is a hardware wallet (Trezor, Ledger, etc) purchased directly from the manufacturer and factory-reset by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to categorise Bitcoin wallets is into two main [types of wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866) - custodial and non-custodial.

A custodial wallet is where you pay a business to look after your money for you.

If you have a custodial wallet that isn't showing the expected balance, you must resolve this by communicating with the business that owes you your money.

In this case it is likely there was a temporary problem (a "glitch") with the custodial-wallet software provided by the business.