# What’s the difference between a Bitpay wallet and a regular bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet, bitcoin-wallet-app, bitpay

Just need to know the difference between the two and what’s the difference between the BitPay wallet and regular bitcoin

Comment: This is very hard to answer without knowing what you see. 1 BTC = 1 BTC, and its current price is indeed around 33000 USD per BTC. Possibly the site is showing mBTC (millibitcoin; 1 BTC = 1000 mBTC), or you're talking about one of the scammy bitcoin clones (which typically will have different symbols than BTC).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kinds of wallets are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/what-kinds-of-wallets-are-there) "Regular bitcoin" is "stored in" a regular wallet (non-custodial AKA self-custodial)

Answer (score 1):

Bitpay is likely holding this bitcoin for you, so you legally own it, but it Is controlled by a custodian. The price of Bitcoin is simply the price you can currently sell that bitcoin for on the market.

If you want to fully own and custody your bitcoin, as you should once you're ready, you should withdraw the bitcoin to a personal wallet like Wasabi or Electrum, so that you no longer have to trust BitPay.

Comment: This is all true, but I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: honestly, the question makes no sense to me. I think they were confused after hearing "not your keys, not your coins" or something like that.