# I have forgotten my Blockchain account password and 12 word recovery. I have the wallet id and password to the wallet. Can i get my funds back?

Tags: blockchain, wallet-recovery, currencies, source-code, funds

I have forgotten my Blockchain bitcoin account password and 12 word recovery(possibly didn't even create one). However I do have my wallet id and the password to the wallet. Is there a way to get the funds? I read about some stuff of brute forcing the password or using something like a dust attack to get the funds out. Would this work? Thanks for any help

Comment: Related: [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/5406)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **[custodial account](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/81246/13866)** with Exchange.blockchain.com, you must contact them for help. They own the money, not you (*"Not your keys -- not your bitcoin"*).

If you have a **non-custodial wallet** downloaded from Blockchain.com, you should normally recover control over your money by restoring the wallet from a backup or from a safely stored record of either the recovery-phrase or the private-key. If you have none of these, you have lost control of the money.

---

References

- [Blockchain.com custodial account](https://exchange.blockchain.com/trade)
- [Blockchain.com non-custodial wallet](https://www.blockchain.com/wallet)

> Write Down Your Backup Phrase
>
> Your backup phrase is the most important of all security measures. It is the key to ensuring your access to your funds if you forget your password or Blockchain is unavailable.