# Unable to view coinbase transactions on blockchain.com

Tags: blockchain, coinbase.com

I'm trying to view some of the transactions I've made on [coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/dashboard) on [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/?utm_campaign=expnav_logo). I copied  my btc wallet address from coinbase and searched it on blockchain.com -- nothing showed up.

Why is this the case?

Per my understanding, given that coinbase *stores* my btc inside blockchain-powered wallets after I buy them, I should have been able to see all of my transactions.

Comment: Did you pay one Coinbase user account from another Coinbase user account for the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Since a Coinbase account is [custodial](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866), Coinbase can move money from internal account to internal account without recording it on the blockchain. These sort of internal transactions between Coinbase and its customers are not normal Bitcoin transactions. So far as the Bitcoin network is concerned, Coinbase own the money not you.

I'm not sure what a Coinbase account "BTC wallet address" would be, but I guess either it isn't a valid Bitcoin address (but instead something proprietary and internal to Coinbase) or it was mis-typed or just hasn't been used yet for any on-chain transactions.