# Bitcoin recovery possible from some kind of private key?

Tags: wallet-recovery, instawallet

back in 2012 I've acquired a small amount of bitcoins, which as far as I remember I saved in a wallet on instantwallet. I wasn't following what was happening with the bitcoin until I listened lately about its value. I also found out that instawallet does not exist anymore since it was hacked in 2014.

Apart from a URL on instawallet, I have a Bitcoin address and some kind of a private key. Could somenone please tell me for sure if there is any chance to recover my bitcoins or should I just forget it?

Answer (score 4):

### Recovery using a private key

If your private key looks like a proper Bitcoin [private key](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key), you can recover control over your money.

A private key is just a large number. There are several different ways of representing that number.

| Representation | Example |
| --- | --- |
| Hexadecimal | E9873D79C6D87DC0FB6A5778633389F4453213303DA61F20BD67FC233AA33262 |
| Base58 WIF | 5Kb8kLf9zgWQnogidDA76MzPL6TsZZY36hWXMssSzNydYXYB9KF |
| Mini private key | SzavMBLoXU6kDrqtUVmffv |

<sup>(Don't use these values they are just examples)</sup>

Note the specific lengths and the specific mixtures of characters. I think WIF normally starts with a "5". Your private key needs to match these characteristics.

[Wallet Import Format (WIF)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format) is probably the most useful.

You should be able to [choose a wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) and "import" or "sweep" your private key.  Sweeping is considered safer because it works better with normal backups and recovery-phrases of the new wallet.

---

### Instawallet

If you used Instawallet, it seems unlikely that you have a true private key.

See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Instawallet

> Instawallet's service learned that its security was compromised and on April 3rd, 2013 closed the service. Those with funds in their Instawallet can file a claim form to get their funds.

This sort of issue is why [custodial wallets](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866) are inadvisable for long term storage.