# I am looking for a software named instawallet used as a bitcoin wallet in 2011

Tags: wallet, client, instawallet

I am looking for instawallet a windows vista desktop software bitcoin wallet that produces mnemonics.  If you know of a download link or have a copy of the software, please let me know.

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103446/13866

Comment: there is also a software named instawallet. i used it in march of 2011. mnemonic producing window s desktop wallet similar to electrum. bitcoin wallet

Comment: At least BIP39 was only proposed in 2013, so I would be surprised if you had a wallet that produced mnemonics in 2011. If you have a mnemonic, you can probably use a generic recovery tool, though.—If you would like to clarify your question, please edit the question post instead of adding answer posts.

Comment: Are you sure your wallet wasn't Electrum version 1? It had mnemonic seed-phrases two years before the 2013 BIP-39 standard, so presumably in 2011.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Instawallet), Instawallet was launched in April 2011 (you're probably misremembering using it in March) and closed in 2013 after a [hack](https://www.businessinsider.com/instawallet-suspended-2013-4). Because it was a web wallet, there is no software for you to download to recover the funds.

The wiki claims that users of Instawallet "can file a claim form to get their funds", but I couldn't find a source for this and the website is down anyway so I don't know where you'd file that claim.

Comment: I used the instawallet desktop software for my first bitcoin wallet. I have the mnemonic from march 2011 but cant find the software for download. the standards of the wallet in particular the wordlist was different i think and was not adopted into the bitcoin standards later in 2011 and 2012.  interesting that all the sudden here in 2023 I finds a company with the same name as instawallet desktop wallet.  I have been in the bitcoin arena since 2011 and first heard of instawallet online service in 2023.  wtf.  Just when i need the desktop software.