# Final Balance -Balance showing different then Coinspot BTC wallet

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, transaction-verification, balance, funds

Bit of a beginner question

I have been using crypto wallets for a few months and have basically learned through trial and error.

The question is my BTC wallet on Coinspot has a $0 and 0.0 BTC balance.
However when I check my BTC wallet address on btc.com or blockchain explorer etc it shows a Final Balance/balance of a small amount of BTC.

https://btc.com/19xJAVY3XHnKr24XjbMX3ZRhiTL1DRDpMi

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/19xJAVY3XHnKr24XjbMX3ZRhiTL1DRDpMi

I'm not sure why it's different (guessing it's transaction fees or some error)  if the final balance is correct and my coinspot wallet balance is wrong/showing 0.0 what/how do I get access to it...

Comment: The coinspot wallet is a [custodial wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866). It is an account with a business, not a [normal wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) where you alone have access to private-keys. Therefore any money is in the hands of the custodian, Coinspot. Probably only they can help identify what has happened to the money under their control.

Comment: Thanks, @RedGrittyBrick it explains a lot in a brief summary.
I did email them prior and the reply wasn't very helpful 

"When reviewing your CoinSpot accounts balances, we strongly recommend that you refer directly to the 'Order History' within your CoinSpot account.
A complete breakdown of the transactions conducted within your CoinSpot account can be found there, I have included a link below -
https://www.coinspot.com.au/my/orders/open"

 - I'll reply to their email and reword it a bit to see what the answer is and know what to do if it happens with another exchange Custodial wallet