# How can I recover my Copay app after forgetting my PIN?

Tags: wallet-recovery, copay

I cannot access my Copay app because I forgot my PIN number. My app is locked with the PIN number. How can I recover it?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/bitpay/copay

> Copay wallet is now Bitpay Wallet. Repo at https://github.com/bitpay/wallet

So you shouldn't be using the Copay app.

it also says

> WE HAVE DETECTED SOME FAKE COPAY WALLETS ON THE GOOGLE PLAY STORE FOR ANDROID THAT WILL STEAL YOUR COINS

So you need to be certain you have a genuine non-malicious app.

---

If you have an old Copay [non-custodial](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866) wallet app, and have forgotten it's password, and did not make unencrypted backups, and did not write down a recovery phrase or equivalent,  it is probable that the only hope is to use a brute-force guessing tool like BTCrecover (not an endorsement) along with anything you can recall about the length, composition and structure of the "PIN".

Remember that the most important job of the app is to keep out people who don't know the "PIN".