# Do wallet companies send user's transactions to their own "central" bitcoin nodes?

Tags: transactions, wallet, nodes

Do external wallets companies such as muun, bluewallet, or greenwallet send user's TXs to some "centralized" data center where they own some nodes to broadcast the TX to the blockchain?

If it is so, is this a good privacy / self sovereignity practice?

Can I use an external wallet, and make it send transactions to my own node or am I forced to use bitcoin core native wallet in order to broadcast by myself transactions?

Sorry if any of this post's premises / questions make no sense. My assumption is that if external wallets didn't exist, I would have to make my own TX and broadcast them to the blockchain with my own node, so if external wallets do exist and I do not run a node, do they use their own "centralized" nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on trusted third parties is not good practice. It contradicts the objectives of the original developer of Bitcoin.

Most normal wallets can construct transactions and transmit them to a few other peer nodes.

Some wallets are lightweight wallets which don't store their own copy of the blockchain. They rely on servers to some extent. However they can transmit their transactions themselves.

See

- [What kinds of wallets are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866)