# Old Blockchain Wallet App Not Working (android)

Tags: blockchain, wallet

I have the Blockchain wallet app most recent version (yet, years old) everytime I try to login it says "error connecting to server" And I have the internet and 4 digit pin, and this app is not available anymorr om play store (they changed app name and apk) i have tons of btc i dont have phrase, please help if you know how to access old blockchain app wallet, regards amanda.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is a [custodial wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866) the only people who can help are the wallet's custodians (blockchain.com).

If the app is a non-custodial wallet (arguably the safest kind) - you should restore from backups or seed phrase or use seed-phrase or master private keys in a [different still-supported non-custodial wallet app](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet). If you didn't make a safe copy of the seed-phrase or master private key and have no backups then all money is lost and cannot ever be retrieved.