# What is "blockchain hang/hung"?

Tags: transactions, fraud

I sent Btc to an address. I verified address. Verified with my wallet that it was sent successfully. Receiving party sees the transaction, but say it is still "pending" on their end. Said it is "hung" in the blockchain. Funds have been removed from my wallet. How do I find it/fix it? Was also told to send it again, same amount, within 7 days, and original will be reversed and sent back to me. Not sure if that's trustworthy? Any help would be nice, especially to know how to not have this happen. again.

Answer (score 2):

The receiving party appears to be lying to you

> Receiving party sees the transaction, but say it is still "pending" on their end.

There is no such thing as "pending" in standard Bitcoin transactions where the receiver has a normal "[self-custodial](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866)" type of wallet.

Furthermore, for normal Bitcoin transactions between normal (self-custodial) wallets, the receiving wallets play no part in receiving money after they provided the sender with the receiving address. The recipient can receive money even if the device holding their wallet is turned off, is defective, broken or has been destroyed.

Once your transaction is recorded in the blockchain you have done everything that is necessary and can do no more. Any problems the recipient claims to have are not your concern and do not change the fact that they have received the money and have exclusive control over it.

> Said it is "hung" in the blockchain.

This simply is not possible. If the transaction is recorded in the blockchain, it is thereby confirmed and has already completed. There is no further step.

> Funds have been removed from my wallet.  How do I find it/fix it?

Look for the transaction-Id (txid) in your wallet - you can check the state of the transaction in any "[bitcoin explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+explorer)".

> Was also told to send it again, same amount, within 7 days,

Someone wants to steal more than they already stole.

> and original will be reversed and sent back to me.

Bitcoin transactions are irreversible, they cannot ever be cancelled, undone or reversed.

> Not sure if that's trustworthy?

What you describe looks completely untrustworthy to me.