# BTC transfer sitting on blockchain.com

Tags: wallet-recovery, lost-bitcoins

If you mistakenly sent a BTC transfer to a deleted wallet with a lost recovery phrase and the transaction is still on blockchain.com. Is there a way to get the transaction placed in a blockchain account or sent to another wallet? The transaction says it's been mined and has a block number, does that mean I lost it? If so how long would I have to recover if there is any possible way?

Comment: Best contact customer support of the wallet your are using if you are having trouble with it.

Answer (score 2):

A confirmed Bitcoin transaction cannot be undone. The money is under the control of whoever knows the private-key for the receiving address.

If the receiving address is one for which nobody has the private-key, then that money can never be spent.

If the wallet was [non-custodial](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866), was deleted, no backups kept and the recovery-phrase lost, there is no way to obtain the private-key.

If a non-custodial wallet was very recently deleted and the computer taken out of use, there may be a tiny chance that data-recovery tools can retrieve the deleted wallet data from a low-level copy of the disk or other persistent storage used.

If the wallet, and its data, was password protected and no details of the password are known then even a recovered data file is of no use.