# How can I doublecheck the value stored in a paper wallet?

Tags: exchange-rate, paper-wallet, wallet-import

I have a paper wallet with some bitcoins that I bought in 2017. It says *Balance 0.03614145 BTC* but when I scan the QR-code with the private key, it says *Balance €163.18*; shouldn't the balance be more than that?

Comment: Paper wallets are useful means to store Bitcoin in a secure fashion that allows the value of a wallet to be transferred if the owner chooses to transfer ownership (holding) of the paper wallet and is where the idea that the owner of the private keys, that is, a person who can spend the Bitcoin is the owner.

Comment: Hi michelle, could you please clarify what you mean with "it says"? Is this in both cases the wallet that you imported the key from the paper wallet into, or is the bitcoin balance stated on the paper wallet printout?—Rather than just tagging the topic, we prefer when the titles of topics capture the gist of the question. I’ve edited your question’s title to summarize what you are asking about. Please feel free to edit it further or roll that back, if I misunderstood the intent of your question.

Answer (score 2):

> **shouldnt the balance be more than that?**

At [today's exchange rates](https://www.google.com/search?q=BTC+to+euro) (₿1:€47117), your ₿0.03614145 is worth €1702 not €163

> **when i scan the QR (private key)**

The result of this depends what exactly you mean.

Importing an address (not private key) into a non-custodial wallet and rescanning the blockchain is a way of checking the balance. You only need import the private key if you want to spend money or if the wallet is intended to be a cold-wallet.

Putting a private key into a randomly selected untrusted website invites theft.

---

- [What kinds of wallets are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866)

Comment: Paper wallets are not useless if they are left on the bench unopened with the Private Key secure, but otherwise after they are spent the wallet can still be refilled.